# How do I avoid Python Unicode encoding error when reading in a text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written the following Python code, which uses the folder selected by the user (data_fold) to navigate through the text files in the folder that contain the data.

```
rootdir = self.data_fold;
   for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            file2read = open(os.path.join(subdir, file));
            data = file2read.read();                       
            file2read.close();
            data;
```

I get the following errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "PIM_Reporter.py", line 71, in genPimPlot
self.ExtractPIMDataFromFiles(self.data_fold);
File "PIM_Reporter.py", line 75, in ExtractPIMDataFromFiles
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 278, in walk
names = listdir(top)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, list found
```

I need the code to do a few things: open the file, read the data in, add the data to a dictionary, close the file. I am new to Python, so explicit solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: The error appears to come from `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):` and therefore is not explicitly associated with what you're trying to do in the bottom paragraph or the question title.

Comment: print `rootdir`. `os.walk` expects string but you probably use list.

Comment: print of rootdir gave me: ['C:/Users/qlab/Desktop/nsiReporter/pim/pimDataEx/R1']

Comment: Maybe `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir[0]):` will work then? Since you're getting a list with one element

Comment: If that does work then the actual question you've asked is relatively simple but building a dictionary is not possible if you don't give an indication of the file structure and the expected outcome

Comment: Thank you both @furas & roganjosh. The problem was that the rootdir was a list. The solution I used was to redefine the rootdir as: rootdir = ''.join(self.data_fold);

Comment: Can I read the file without opening it?

Comment: no, you can't read without opening.

Comment: @Connor could you read a book without opening it? But on a serious level, why is that a concern for you? Calling `open` on a gigantic file will not consume all your memory, only if you try to load it into memory.

Comment: If you solved, you should post your answer.

Comment: As @AaronHall wrote, post your answer. Purpose of SO is to maintain a database of answers to questions, so that everyone who encounters the same problem can find the solution which helped others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try this

```
import os
d = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path'):
    for file in files:
        print(file)
        with open(os.path.join(root,file)) as f:
            d[file]= f.read()
            f.close()
print(d)
```

**output:**
{'file1':'data','file2':'data',.......}